# Requisições sequenciais usando métodos assíncronos do Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo onde é necessário fazer a sincronização dos dados em determinados momentos.Eu estou usando Retrofit para fazer a conexão com a api e enviar/receber os dados, mas cada requisição precisa ser feita apenas quando a requisição anterior terminar. Como é possível fazer isso?

Interface com as requisições:

```
public interface DownloadService {

@GET("ciclo/current")
Call<JsonObject> getCicloAtual(@Header("Authorization") String token);

@GET("ciclo/last")
Call<JsonObject> getCicloLast(@Header("Authorization") String token);

@GET("imoveis")
Call<JsonObject> getImoveis(@Header("Authorization") String token);

@GET("pessoas")
Call<JsonObject> getPessoas(@Header("Authorization") String token);}
```

O cliente:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static String BASE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8000/api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){
    if(retrofit == null) {
        return retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

public static AuthService authService() {return  getInstance().create(AuthService.class);}

public static DownloadService downloadService() {return  getInstance().create(DownloadService.class);}

public static SyncService syncService(){
    return  getInstance().create(SyncService.class);
}}
```

Comment: A requisição seguinte deve ser feita no método onde recebe o resultado da requisição anterior.

Comment: Tem alguma outra forma? Ainda tem muitas requisições a serem feitas além dessas 4 do código e eu não queria que ficasse desarrumado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com as `Call`s do retrofit não há muitas possibilidades sem ser no método `onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response)` das `Callback`s tal como explicado nos comentários.

Um exemplo seria:

```java
Retrofit instance = getInstance();
instance.getCicloAtual("token")
   .enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response) {
            // Aqui a gente faz a próxima call
            instance.getCicloLast("token")
               .enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                  // e por aí fora
               });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}
    });
```

Não vai ser o código mais bonito do mundo, mas vai funcionar.

---

Outra forma é chamar as `Call`s sincronamente. Contudo, tem que ser tudo feito noutra thread que não seja a `main`. Por exemplo, podemos fazer:

```java
Retrofit instance = getInstance();
new Thread(() -> {
    JsonObject result = instance.getCicloAtual("token").execute();
    // a próxima linha só corre quando a de cima terminar
    result = instance.getCicloLast("token");
}
```

Este modo tem outros problemas - Temos que tratar de retornar o resultado para quem chamou essas APIs e muito provavelmente na main-thread com ajuda de um `Handler`. Temos que tratar de enventuais excepções e erros. Temos que terminar os requests manualmente se por exemplo a aplicação fôr posta em background.

---

Outra hipótese é usar um `CallAdapter` que não usa `Callbacks`. Pode ser por exemplo `RxJava` ou coroutines. Com estes call adapters, embora o código seja asincrono, escreve-se como se fosse sincrono. Assim não fica nada desarrumado, mas provavelmente introduz muito diferença no código que tens agora.

Espero que ajude.